# Pack color channel bytes into a signed integer and display correctly as hex

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, unsigned-integer

I am attempting to pack color channel bytes into a signed integer, but the resulting integer will not display correctly as hexadecimal since it is signed. Is there an easy way to do this in JavaScript. Unfortunately I cannot declare an unsigned integer.

> `#-FFFF01` or `-16776961`

Should result in:

> `#FF0000FF` or `4278190335`

```js
[
  [ 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)' ],
  [ 'rgb(34, 12, 64)' ],
  [ 'rgb(34, 12, 64, 0.6)' ],
  [ 'rgba(34, 12, 64, 0.6)' ],
  [ 'rgb(34 12 64 / 0.6)' ],
  [ 'rgba(34 12 64 / 0.3)' ],
  [ 'rgb(34.0 12 64 / 60%)' ],
  [ 'rgba(34.6 12 64 / 30%)' ],
  [  34, 12, 64, 0.3 ]
].forEach(analyze);

/*
 * @param {int|String} r [0, 255] or rgba?()
 * @param {int} g [0, 255]
 * @param {int} b [0, 255]
 * @param {Number} a [0, 1]
 */
function rgba2int(r, g, b, a) {
  if (typeof r === 'string' && arguments.length === 1) {
    const [r1, g1, b1, a1] = r
      .match(/^rgba?\((\d+\.?\d*)[,\s]*(\d+\.?\d*)[,\s]*(\d+\.?\d*)[,\s\/]*(.+)?\)$/)
      .slice(1);    
    [r, g, b] = [r1, g1, b1].map(v => parseFloat(v));
    a = a1
      ? a1.endsWith('%')
        ? parseInt(a1.substring(0, a1.length - 1), 10) / 100
        : parseFloat(a1)
      : null;
  }
  return a
    ? ((r & 0xFF) << 24) + ((g & 0xFF) << 16) + ((b & 0xFF) << 8) + (Math.floor(a * 0xFF) & 0xFF)
    : ((r & 0xFF) << 16) + ((g & 0xFF) << 8) + (b & 0xFF);
}

function analyze(input) {
  const res = rgba2int(...input);
  console.log([
    input.join(' ').padEnd(24, ' '),
    res.toString(10).padStart(10, ' '),
    ('#' + res.toString(16)).padStart(11, ' ')
  ].join(''));
}
```

```css
.example { display: inline-block; width: 32px; height: 32px; }
.example-1 { background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0); }
.example-2 { background: rgb(34, 12, 64); }
.example-3 { background: rgb(34, 12, 64, 0.6); }
.example-4 { background: rgba(34, 12, 64, 0.6); }
.example-5 { background: rgb(34 12 64 / 0.6); }
.example-6 { background: rgba(34 12 64 / 0.3); }
.example-7 { background: rgb(34.0 12 64 / 60%); }
.example-8 { background: rgba(34.6 12 64 / 30%); }
```

```html
<!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color#Syntax -->
<div class="example example-1"></div>
<div class="example example-2"></div>
<div class="example example-3"></div>
<div class="example example-4"></div>
<div class="example example-5"></div>
<div class="example example-6"></div>
<div class="example example-7"></div>
<div class="example example-8"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  return a
    ? (((r & 0xFF) << 24) + ((g & 0xFF) << 16) + ((b & 0xFF) << 8) + (Math.floor(a * 0xFF) & 0xFF)) >>> 0
    : (((r & 0xFF) << 16) + ((g & 0xFF) << 8) + (b & 0xFF)) >>> 0;
```

Comment: I assume you are referencing this [_**MDN > "Unsigned right shift (>>>)"**_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift)? _"Unlike the other bitwise operators, zero-fill right shift returns an unsigned 32-bit integer."_ Also, I guess you could just wrap the ternary condition and shift the result of that?

Comment: if i had knew "why" it works, i had mentioned it, but I do unfortunately know only the "how", sorry.